# css - all link's color change when set a:visited in IE8

Tags: html, css, sass

Here is my css about `a` element. All browser works well except IE8.
In IE8, all of my link's color change to `$color-purple`, no matter whether they are clicked or not.

```
a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $color-blue;

    &:hover, &:focus {
        color: $color-blue-dark;
    }

    &:visited {
        color: $color-purple;
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: This could be your answer. Apparently :visited has been disabled due to security issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620122/visited-links-color-not-changing-in-ie-8

Answer (score 2):

The `:visited` pseudo class has been disabled to prevent "sniffing" for which sites a visitor has been to in the past; this was regarded as a privacy concern.

You could check the computed styles for a link and look at the color, if it had the `:visited` color, you could infer that the user had been to that site before.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848869(v=vs.85).aspx

The problem might also be that you've visited the link destinations in the past? To test, clear your browser history.

Comment: I've tested on 3 pc, but the result is the same. All links's color change to `$color-purple`.

Comment: @user2331095 can you post the relevant section of your rendered css in the question? I can look further.